# quality gate in jenkins pipeline is failing , but the quality gate is saying error not failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

```
stage("Quality Gate"){
        when{
            expression { params.Env == 'DEV'}
            }
        steps {
            timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
```

output:

```
Checking status of SonarQube task 'AYXqx14e8y4YGb0qU2rE' on server ' SonarQube'
SonarQube task 'AYXqx14e8y4YGb0qU2rE' status is 'SUCCESS'
SonarQube task 'AYXqx14e8y4YGb0qU2rE' completed. Quality gate is 'ERROR'
```

I configured webhooks in sonarqube  it was working fine earlier and passed showed in sonar but it is now showing above error and build is failing

I want to know how to fix this and get this passed

Comment: Maybe the code has been changed, and now you have more errors/warning and it starts to fail?

Comment: Can you run the sonar analysis in verbose mode and see for any errors ?